# If a matrix-valued function converges element-wise (at the same rate) to a constant matrix, do the eigenvectors also converge element-wise?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, perturbation-theory

If a matrix valued function $\psi(\lambda)$ converges element-wise as to a constant matrix $A$(all elements converging at the same rate) as $\lambda\to\infty$, can we say that all the eigenvectors of the matrix $\psi(\lambda)$ converge element-wise to the eigenvectors of the matrix $A$?

PS at same rate, I mean all elements are Asymptotically as $\lambda\to\infty$  are of the form $A + B\Theta(\frac{1}{\lambda})$

PS2 : By eigen vectors I mean normalized eigen vectors which form an orthonormal basis. Assume $\psi(\lambda)$ is symmetric and positive definite always. $A$ is symmetric but may be singular.

PS3 : All matrices are real valued.

**More clarity**

1. Assume eigenvalues are also converging $\Theta(\frac{1}{\lambda})$ to eigenvalues of $A$.
2. Let $e_1(\lambda),e_2(\lambda),e_3(\lambda),...e_n(\lambda)$ be the normalized eigenvectors of $\psi(\lambda)$ in decreasing order of corresponding eigenvalues.

Let $E(\lambda) = [e_1(\lambda),e_2(\lambda),...e_n(\lambda)]$ be a matrix whose columns are normalized eigenvectors. let $D(\lambda)$ be a diagonal matrix whose elements eigenvalues of $\psi(\lambda)$ in the same order of eigenvectors.

Now $\psi(\lambda) = E(\lambda)D(\lambda)E(\lambda)^T$ and as eigenvalues $D$ is converging elementwise with same asymptotics, shouldn't $E(\lambda)$ converge element-wise?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "all elements converging at the same rate"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : I mean all elements are Asymptotically of form $A + B\Theta(\frac{1}{\lambda})$

Comment: If you take the constant sequence of the identity matrix $I$ then you can pick eigenvectors that roam randomly in space without converging. So you need to put more conditions.

Comment: I mean normalized eigen vectors which form an orthonormal basis. Assume $\psi(\lambda)$ is symmetric and pd always.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a symmetric positive-definite matrix. Let $R$ be a rotation by $\pi/2$ in some axis, and let $\psi(n)=B_n:=\frac{1}{n}R^nCR^{-n}$.

There are issues when an eigenspace has dimension more than 1 (as in the comments), but let us suppose that $C$ has a unique eigenvector $v$ for some specific eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $B_n$ has eigenvector $R^nv$ with eigenvalue $\lambda/n$.

Thus $B_n\to A=0$ ($\|B_n\|=\|C\|/n\to0$), its eigenvalue $\lambda/n\to0$, but its corresponding eigenvectors $R^nv$ do not converge.

(Note: $E_n=R^n[v_1,\ldots,v_n]=[R^nv_1,\ldots,R^nv_n]$ does not converge component-wise.)

---

Second Example: Let $\psi(n):=\begin{pmatrix}1&\tfrac{1}{n}\\\tfrac{1}{n}&1\end{pmatrix}$ when $n$ is odd, and $\begin{pmatrix}1+\tfrac{1}{n}&0\\0&1-\tfrac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}$ for $n$ even. The eigenvalues of $\psi(n)$ are $1\pm\tfrac{1}{n}$ irrespective of parity, but with corresponding eigenvectors $(1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, when $n$ is odd, and $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ when $n$ is even. Thus the diagonalizing matrix $E_n=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ for $n$ odd and $I$ for $n$ even. Clearly $E_n$ does not converge, even though their eigenvalues do, and $\psi(n)\to I$.

Comment: I have edited to add that eigenvalues also converge to that of $A$. I had made this edit paralelly and before I could see your answer.

Comment: The eigenvalues necessarily converge because they are continuous functions of the coefficients of $B_n$.

Comment: I mean eigenvalues converge to that of $A$. In your example they are not converging to that of $A$.

Comment: How? The eigenvalues of $B_n$ are $\lambda/n$ and those of $A=0$ are $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does your method work when $A$ is a nonzero matrix? (with suitable modifications)?

Comment: I am asking because in my application, $A$ is a nonzero matrix, that is not all elements of $A$ are zero.

Comment: The question allowed singular matrices for $A$. That's why I commented immediately that more conditions are needed.

Comment: Yes $A$ is singular. I appreciated your answer. But asking if $A$ is singular but nonzero matrix. For example $A$ is all ones matrix?(its still singular) Can your example be modified to serve as a counter example for this case. Once again your answer is complete and serves the actual question. I just asking this extra question that $A$ is singular but nonzero.

Comment: I'll have to think about it. If you take the $3\times3$ matrix of $1$s, it has a plane of two eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$. So there probably is a sequence of matrices converging to it, with eigenvectors rotating about in this plane. The point is that if $B_n\to A$ and $\lambda_n\to \lambda$ then $((B_n-\lambda_n)-(A-\lambda))w_n\to0$ anyway, even if $w_n$ do not converge.

Comment: $E(\lambda)$ are already $O(1)$ as they are normalized. To prove convergence, $\psi(\lambda) = E(\lambda)D(\lambda)E(\lambda)^T$, if not all elements of the diagonal matrix $D$ converge to zero, then can we say that all elements of $E(\lambda)$ must converge as $\psi(\lambda)$ has to converge element-wise. Is there any flaw in this argument?

Comment: Davis-Kahan theorem bounds the sin of the angle between the eigenvectors. There are also results that bound the $l^{\infty}$ norm between the eigenvectors (this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03516.pdf )

Comment: I think you need to add the condition that all eigenvalues are distinct in order to say something about individual eigenvectors.

Comment: These theorems do not require that they are distinct. Only need atleast one eigenvalue to be nonzero.

Comment: The Davis-Kahan theorem bounds the angle between *eigenspaces*, not individual eigenvectors.

Comment: There is an $l^{\infty}$ modification, see the paper  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03516.pdf It talks about individual eigenvectors. Theorem 2.2

Comment: Theorem 2.1 of that paper involves an "unspecified" rotation when there are multiple eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue.

Comment: soon after theorem 2.1, they say "... the individual eigenvectors of V are
only identifiable up to rotation. However, assuming an eigengap (similar to Davis-Kahan theorem), we are able to bound the perturbation of individual eigenvectors (up to sign)." and that is theorem 2.2.

Comment: To quote that theorem: "the interval $[λ_i − \delta, λ_i +\delta]$ does not contain any eigenvalues of $A$ other than $λ_i$"; in other words, the eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: yes that doesn't exclude $\lambda_i$ being present again, as they say " other than $\lambda_i$". So $\lambda_i$ can be there second time. I don't know, just trying to clarify. What if $\lambda_i = \lambda_{i+1}$

Comment: You're right. Still, the theorem does not compare arbitrary eigen-spaces $V$ and $\tilde{V}$ but $V$ with the rotated eigenvectors $R\tilde{v}$. The eigenvectors cannot be allowed to roam freely, as the second example in the amended answer shows.

Comment: Your second example doesn't qualify as a perturbation. Look at point 1 (under more clarity) of my question. Also you example is not inline with definition of an analytic perturbationA simple perturbation is $\tilde{A} = A +\epsilon H$ and we should investigate in some neighbourhood of $\epsilon = 0$. If you have higher power terms of $\epsilon$ then its called an analytic perturbation.

Comment: $H=\frac{1}{n}\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$